# How do I break down this derivation further?

Tags: logic

I'm trying to prove the following is a tautology by using logical derivation and without the use of truth tables:
$$((P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee (\neg Q))) \to P.$$

So far I got:
$$(\neg ((P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee \neg Q))) \vee P, \\
    (\neg (P \vee Q) \vee \neg (P \wedge \neg Q)) \vee P, \\
    (\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q) \vee P.$$

I honestly can't see a way to go any further with this.

Comment: If you are proving this is equivalent to a tautology, and therefore a theorem, you need to say something about what rules of inference are legal. What are your rules of inference?

Comment: sorry..im in a first year logic class and we haven't covered rules of inference ._. Not sure what you're talking about sowi.

Answer (score 1):

One can directly get

$$\begin{array}{cc}
&[(P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee (\lnot Q))] \rightarrow P \\
\Longrightarrow&[(P \vee (Q \wedge \lnot Q)] \rightarrow P \\
\Longrightarrow&P \rightarrow P
\end{array}$$
which is of course always true

Comment: I'm not sure how you got to the second step..what rule is that? how did you just join the (q and not q) together?

Comment: $Q\wedge\lnot Q$ is false, now $P\vee 0 = P$

Answer (score 1):

Also by conjunction distribution you can continue with

$(\neg P\wedge(\neg Q\vee Q))\vee P$

But ($\neg Q\vee Q$) is a taytology, always true. And a conjunction of truth and a formula, results to the formula only. So, $P\wedge(\neg Q\vee Q)\to P$.
So, you have

$\neg P\vee P$

Tautology

Answer (score 0):

Break it down to premises and use rules of derivation:
Every line ends with $P$ for premise or line numbers and $T$ for tautology.

We use the 3 rules of derivation (Patrick Suppes's introduction to logic, section 2.2):

Rule P:

List all premises.

Rule T:

A tautology may follow from the preceding premises.

Rule C.P. (conditional proof):

If set of premises $w_1,...w_n$ and additional premise $R$ imply $S$

then $R\implies S$ can be derived from set of premises $w_1,...w_n$ alone.

$\{1\}\; (1) \;p\lor q\implies p$ P

$\{2\} \;(2) \;p\lor\neg q\implies p$ P

$\{3\} \;(3) \;(p \lor q)\land (p\lor \neg q)$ C.P

$\{3\}\; (4) \; p\land (q\lor \neg q)$ 3T (distributive law)

$\{1,2\}\;(5)\; p\land (q\lor \neg q)\implies p$ law of simplification and law of excluded middle.